# Dos valores para un solo input

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando hacer algo así:

```
<input type="text" value="Equipo A" name="nombre">
<input type="text" value="Logo A" name="logo">
```

Pasarlo a algo como esto:

```
<input type="text" value1="Equipo A" name1="txtNombre" value2="Logo A" name2="txtLogo">
```

Y después guardar esos dos valores en dos variables distintas con php

Comment: ¿Has probado con [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos) de HTML5? No se si sea lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Para trabajarlo en PHP, sólo tomas el valor y usas `explode`, algo así: `$mValues=explode('|',$_POST['val']);` Esto te crea un array en base al separador, por lo que el 1er valor estaría en `$mValues[0]` y el 2do en `$mValues[1]` ... si quieres algo más avanzado y organizado, puedes usar los atributos data. Tampoco eres muy claro explicando el contexto o lo que quieres. Ahora veo que editaste poniendo más cosas.

Comment: Sería interesante saber porque necesitas dos valores. es posible que haya soluciones alternativas

Comment: Tengo un select con una lista de nombres y después esta un por cada nombre input de tipo radio con una imagen. Para no hacer que eligan el nombre y después el input con la imagen.

Answer (score 5):

Ya lo solucione:

```
<input type='text' name='array[]' value='logo.png'>
<input type='text' name='array[]' value='Barcelona'>
```

en php quedo asi:

```
$datos = $_POST['array'];
echo $datos[0]; //logo.png
echo $datos[1]; //Barcelona
```

Gracias por sus respuestas, con su ayuda me fueron guiando a encontrar la solución.